# Improve the speed of for loop over a loaded file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dataset in text file in the following form:

```
5851F42D00000000,1
4BB5F64640B18CCF,2
742D2F7A0AE16FD9,1
76035E090D1F0796,1
6FA72CA540F7702C,3
.
.
.
```

The file contains `500K` rows. My goal is to read the file and convert the hex values to binary. The following code works fine but it is very slow. Is there a trick to make it faster?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(path+ 'dataset.txt', sep=",", header=None)
X = []
y = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    n = int('{:064b}'.format(int(row.values[0], 16)))
    X.append(n)
    y.append(row.values[1])
X = np.asarray(X)
y = np.asarray(y)
```

Comment: What do you mean convert to "binary"? What exactly should `X` look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need of redundant loop and appending to lists.
Use pandas "magic":

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=",", header=None)
x = df[0].apply(lambda x: int('{:064b}'.format(int(x, 16)))).to_numpy()
y = df[1].to_numpy()
print(x, y)
```

Comment: This is a loop. Honestly, dispensing with `pandas` here altogether would improve the speed a  lot.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, this not a loop of appending to 2 lists

Comment: Underneath the hood, that's pretty much what `.apply` does. `.apply` is a *convenience* method. Although they've done some stuff to make it faster in the last  few releases, it's basically a for-loop appendig to a list underneath the hood, unless it can detect that there's a vectorized solution possible. In this case, using this function, there isn't.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, "dispensing with pandas" does not prevent any kind of looping

Comment: Yes, you aren't getting away from looping here. `pandas` just adds a whole layer of stuff that is totally useless in this context, slowing things down. Its the worse of both worlds.

Comment: WOW. it is really FAST! Thank you very much

Comment: So, for example, I created a `pd.Series` using `S = pd.Series(['5851F42D00000000', '4BB5F64640B18CCF', '742D2F7A0AE16FD9', '76035E090D1F0796', '6FA72CA540F7702C']*100000)`.Then, you can try timing `S.apply(lambda x: int('{:064b}'.format(int(x, 16))))` vs `[int('{:064b}'.format(int(x, 16))) for x in s]`. I get `583 ms ± 2.55 ms` for `.apply` and `556 ms ± 3.57 ms` for the list comprehension. The fastest way would probably be to just iterate over a `csv.reader` object.

Comment: The fundamental problem with the OP's approach is that they are using `.iterrows`, which is notoriously slow, because it creates a whole new `pd.Series` object on each iteration, incuring a substantial per-iteration overhead that is totally unnecessary here.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, with `csv.reader` you'll have to iterate it twice to obtain 2 arrays (expected as numpy arrays) or iterate through the reader and still `append` to 2 separate lists on each iteration